# approximating function $a+b\cdot 2^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, approximation

Hi I need to implement a function  $a+b\cdot 2^x$ in a highly resource constrained device. a and b are constants and x is a variable. How do I go about finding a simplified version of this expression so that I can get a value almost equal to it, without having to do multiplication, division or exponentiation? the result does not have to be exact, and I can find the new values for a and b empirically. Please help. Thank you

PS: please suggest some new tags for this question, I cannot think of any that are available currently

Comment: I'm not really sure what context you're doing this in, but you can try to round $x$ up or down to the nearest integer in which case the exponentiation becomes a bit-shift. Don't know if this helps you.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines pf using logarithms or something, to reduce the exponentiation and multiplication

Comment: @user13267:  it seems strange to be willing to take logs but not be willing to multiply.  They are usually *much* slower.

Comment: when I was working on this it was for a DSP IC which has a fast logarithm operation. It's not as fast as multiplication, but if I converted all my operations in to logarithms including this one, I was hoping to simplify other parts of the overall program

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing it (in C). `LOG2_B` is $\log_2b$. `0.5` is to make it round to the nearest int, instead of the flooring. The conversion to `int`, though, required to do the bit shift, might cause an unacceptable loss of precision.

`A + 2 << (int)(LOG2_B + x + 0.5)`

Here's a plot of the function (blue) and the above approximation (red) for $a=0, b=1$:

[image]